# How do I create a chained mean in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable in my data frame that is a lagged mean by group.  by this I mean I want every row to show the average of the previous three observations for a particular group.

I've tried using the mutate_at function with lag but it throws an error

```r
laggedmean <- function(x){mean(c(lag(x, 1), lag(x, 2), lag(x, 3)), na.rm = true)}
example <- data.frame(letter = rep(c("a","b","c"), 9), 
                      var1 = 1:27, var2 = 28:54, var3 = 54:80)
example <- example %>%
  group_by(letter)%>%
  mutate_at(c("var1", "var2", "var3"), laggedmean)

Error in mean.default(c(lag(x, 1), lag(x, 2), lag(x, 3)), na.rm = true) : 
 object 'true' not found
```

I've also tried using just mutate to do it one variable at a time, but that doesn't work either. it just produces a single mean for the group

```r
example <- example %>%
  group_by(letter) %>%
  mutate(var1_lag_avg = mean(c(lag(var1, 1), lag(var1, 2),
                                lag(var1, 3)), na.rm = TRUE))
print(example)
# A tibble: 27 x 5
# Groups:   letter [3]
   letter  var1  var2  var3 var1_lag_avg
   <fct>  <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>
 1 a          1    28    54         10.1
 2 b          2    29    55         11.1
 3 c          3    30    56         12.1
 4 a          4    31    57         10.1
 5 b          5    32    58         11.1
 6 c          6    33    59         12.1
 7 a          7    34    60         10.1
 8 b          8    35    61         11.1
 9 c          9    36    62         12.1
10 a         10    37    63         10.1
# ... with 17 more rows
```

The result I'm trying to get would produce NAs for the first three observations of each group and then a chained average that changes with for every subsequent observation.  Instead of all observations of a having a var1_lag_avg of 10.1, the first three would be NA and the fourth would be 4, then the fifth observation for a would be 7, the sixth would be 10 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure why the fourth element should be four rather than 1. How does this fit to your formula which only consideres lagged values. The following code matches your formula but not your desired output. For the latter case, please delete the `lag()`.

```
example %>%
  group_by(letter)%>%
  mutate_at(c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
            list(lagged = ~zoo::rollapply(lag(.), 3, 
                                          mean, na.rm=T, 
                                          partial = T,
                                          fill = NA, align = "right")))
```